# A summary of how to read Romans 1-4 in "Beyond Justification: Liberating Paul's Gospel"?

Tags: paul-apostle, romans, justification, penal-substitution

Can someone give a summary of how to read Romans 1-4 in "[Beyond Justification: Liberating Paul's Gospel](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/205122128-beyond-justification)"?

From a [podcast](https://wipfandstock.com/blog/2024/03/05/douglas-a-campbell-and-jon-depue-liberating-pauls-gospel-from-justification-theory/), I got the idea that Paul actually starts with a Socratic argument, rather than plainly stating what he believes and how things work. I'm not sure if I properly understood it though.

According to the authors of the book, Romans 1-4 is the basis for "Justification Theory", an Atonement Theory often in the form of Penal Substitution.  But 90% of what Paul wrote, "the gospel" as laid out by Paul in the rest of his corpus, doesn't work like that, namely: your faith in Christ is a sign that you are elected and thus saved and equipped to do good works. Perhaps I got that part wrong too, feel free to correct me.

Comment: Welcome to C.SE.  Excellent first question.  Would be great if you could reference the podcast as well.  I placed double quotes between "Justification Theory" since that's the label the authors use, unlike the much more common term "Atonement Theory" in theological literature.  Similarly, it's the authors's label to name the two themes found in Paul as "the gospel" (the 90%) and "another gospel" (the 10%).

Comment: Thanks, I added the link to the podcast

Answer (score 0):

I found a good article here:

https://abjanvanmeerten.medium.com/the-argument-for-a-new-reading-of-romans-1-18-3-20-50bb8d6186d3. If I have time, I'll post a summary here later.

Comment: It would be better to hold off on posting a "link-only" answer and post the summary with a link to the article when you get the time.